# how to fix font issue in wordpress post section

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

How do we fix the font issue in the WordPress post section, The front-end page font is working fine.

I added one different domain in the same hosting panel, and after that, I removed it, apart from not doing anything at my end, I am facing this issue. i have to remove any plugin from wordpress could anyone please help to rectify the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMHTe.png)